# React use axios return Axios Error {message: 'Network Error'} and TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

when I click submit button, then web and terminal will return error like me title
but i try postman is ok , so i think is my axios setting error,how can i fixed this error? I found many similar questions, but can't not help me

the other question is , my form tag action is "/addItems", but i sending request , i got this error  CANNOT POST / addItems    Post http://localhost:3000/addItems 404 (Not Found)

(axios setting )

```
post(id, title, description, price, avatar) {
    let token;
    if (localStorage.getItem("user")) {
      token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).token;
    } else {
      token = "";
    }

    const formData = new FormData();
    // formData.append("id", id);
    // formData.append("title", title);
    // formData.append("description", description);
    // formData.append("price", price);
    formData.append("avatar", avatar);
    return axios.post(
      API_URL + "/addItems",
      { formData },
      {        
headers: {
          Authorization: token,
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        }
      }
    );
}
```

（item.route）

```
itemRouter.post("/addItems", upload.single("avatar"), async (req, res) => {
  let { id, title, description, price, avatar } = req.body;
  if (req.user.isMember()) {
    return res.status(400).send("Only admin can add new items");
  }
  console.log(req.file);
  avatar = req.file.path;

  const newItem = new Item({
    id,
    title,
    description,
    price,
    avatar
  });

  try {
    await newItem.save();
    console.log(req.file);
    res.status(200).send("New item has been saved.");
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).send("Error");
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

(addItemsComponent)

```
 const handleChangePost = () => {
    if (currentUser.user.role !== "admin") {
      window.alert("Member can't not post item!! ");
      navigate("/");
    } else {
      ItemService.post(avatar)
        .then(() => {
          window.alert("Post successfully");
          navigate("/");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          console.log(error.response);
         
          setErrorMessage(error.response.data);
        });
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <form action="/addItems" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input onChange={handleChangeAvatar} value={avatar} type="file" name="avatar" />
        <button type="submit" onClick={handleChangePost}>
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
return axios.post(API_URL + "/addItems", formData,
  {
    headers: {
      Authorization: token,
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: hello! thanks for your comment! when i try your code,  reutrn TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')

Comment: avatar = req.file.path; this line throws that exception. Check what you sending in the request.